# how to update nested state array and then return the entire array react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm using React Hooks. This is my state:

```
const [ chats, setChats ] = useState()
```

And i have this array in my "chats" state:

```
[
    {
        "messages": [ //I refer this field
            {
            "message": "hi",
            "seen": false,
            "_id": "61658b533da2d51eace71b31",
            "user": {"user data"}
            }
        ],
        "users": ["some data"],
        "avatar": "data",
        "_id": "61634b62c1a7612f04296335",
        "type": "private"
        },
    {
      "messages": [],
      "users": ["some data"],
      "avatar": "data",
      "_id": "616355d7e124771d98426240",
      "type": "private"
    }
]
```

So i just need to update the "messages" field from the "0" element of that "chat" array with this `newMessage` object:

```
{
  "message": "another hi",
  "seen": false,
  "_id": "61658f551ccbac34a8d10130",
  "user": {"some user data"}
}
```

I have tried with the most popular answer but it only returns the "messages" field, and **i need to return the entire array**.

Code:

```
setChats([...chats[currentlyChatIndex].messages, newMessage])
```

Comment: I use [immutable-js](https://immutable-js.com/) for list, it would create a whole new object and make react to update

Comment: Updating more complex data structures like this, is more suited to `useReducer` than `useState`. See the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), if you've used Redux before it'll be familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over the array, and if you are at the `currentlyChatIndex` you can append the `messages` field.

#### Example

```js
const data = [
    {
      "messages": 
      [
          {
            "message": "hi",
            "seen": false,
            "_id": "61658b533da2d51eace71b31",
            "user": "user data"
          }
      ],
      "users": ["some data"],
      "avatar": "data",
      "_id": "61634b62c1a7612f04296335",
      "type": "private"
    },
    {
      "messages": [],
      "users": ["some data"],
      "avatar": "data",
      "_id": "616355d7e124771d98426240",
      "type": "private"
    }
]

const addMessage = (index, message) => {
  return data.map((el, i) => i === index ? {...el, messages: [...el.messages, message]} : el)
}

console.log(addMessage(0, {message: 'another hi'}))
```

#### Your case

```
setChats(chats => chats.map((chat, index) => index === currentlyChatIndex ? 
     { ...chat, messages: [...chat.messages, newMessage] } : chat))
```